# Linked List read from file, sorting and off-by-one errors

Tags: java, linked-list, priority-queue

I have to create a linked list that reads a file of Strings and associated int's, and sort at read-time by the int's. So far I've gotten a method to add an element to the list, and a basic read method (but missing the last element from the file for some reason), but every time I try to add conditions to the read method, it returns an empty list.

My add method:

```
public void addFirst(String name, int rank)
{
    Ship newShip = new Ship(name, rank);

    if (isEmpty())
    {
        newShip.next = null;
        newShip.prev = null;
        last = newShip;
        first = newShip;
    }
    else
    {
        first.next = newShip;
        newShip.prev = first;
        first = newShip;
    }
}
```

And my working (but off-by-one) read method:

```
public void readFile(String filename) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
    File inFile = new File(filename);           //inst. file import
    Scanner read = new Scanner(inFile);         //inst. scanner object

    while (read.hasNext())                      //reads until end of text
    {
        String name = read.next();              //scanner reads next string, assigns to name
        int rank = read.nextInt();              //reads next int, assigns to rank
        addFirst(name, rank);                   //enqueues ship name and rank into list
    }
    read.close();                               //ends read when empty
    }

    catch(IOException exc)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: file not found");
    }

}
```

Every time I add a condition to the while() in the read method, like this (and there is a '0' in the data file):

```
    while (read.hasNext())                      //reads until end of text
    {
        String name = read.next();              //scanner reads next string, assigns to name
        int rank = read.nextInt();              //reads next int, assigns to rank
        if (rank == 0)
        {
            addFirst(name, rank);                   //enqueues ship name and rank into list
        }
    }
```

Tt doesn't even seem to read the list at all. I can't start putting conditions in an insertion algorithm if I can't figure out why the add method is busted.

EDIT: Adding a sample data set. I just need to figure out where I'm screwing up conceptually.

ship1    0
   ship2    10
   ship3    27
   ship4    2
   ship5    7
   ....

EDIT2:

Okay, gave up on figuring out insertion using linked lists for now and will just create a sentinel-based insertion read() method. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: add your sample data which you are reading from file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using your `readFile` method, it seems to work fine with me, properly reading the file!
But there seems to be an error in your `addFirst(String name, int rank)`

What you actually do in your `else` condition is you add the `newShip` as the second element (after the first element) but you don't take care of the fact that there might be more items after the first element! Neither you take care of the `next` of the `newShip`.

For example: If your list is:: (Though with the code you have you won't be able to make a Linked List like this! Example is just to explain)

`1<-->2<-->3-->NULL` `first` pointing to `1`

Then after you add a new element `4`

Your link will look something like this::

`1<-->4<-->DANGLING` `first` pointing to `4`

and

`1<--2<-->3-->NULL` `No pointer through which we can this part of the Linked List!`

Take care of the angle brackets I have used, it is the direction of the pointer!

It seems that you are trying to add to the front of the linked list!
So, your code shall look some thing like this!!

```
public void addFirst(String name, int rank)
{
    Ship newShip = new Ship(name, rank);

    if (isEmpty())
    {
        newShip.next = null;
        newShip.prev = null;
        last = newShip;
        first = newShip;
    }
    else
    {
        first.prev = newShip;
        newShip.next = first;
        newShip.prev = NULL; // to ensure there are no dangling pointers
        first = newShip;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just asking here as it's too big for a comment:

Assuming the `addFirst` method is for adding to the head of the linked list and the Ships do indeed have the attributes `next` and `prev`, wouldn't you want:

```
if(!isEmpty){

    first.prev = newShip;
    newShip.next = first;
    first = newShip;

}
```

or if you want to add at the tail of the linked list wouldn't you want:

```
if(!isEmpty){

    last.next = newShip;
    newShip.prev = last;

    // take out first = newShip

}
```

Either way, it seems what you have may not be right. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If he's adding to tail of linked list, it shall be `last.next = newShip` and `newShip.prev = last`

Comment: You're right, that's what I get for pasting code. You clearly have the more detailed answer anyways